# header image in wordpress not loading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I am new to Wordpress. I have to change a wordpress theme. When I change the header image, by simply going to Appearence -> header menu, it uploads the image but the image is not getting displayed on the website? 
Please can anyone help me. I am very new in this.

Comment: You have to add more information - can we see your link?

Comment: @CaptainRon -  sure...it is http://www.everydaycalifornia.com/blog/

Here, I want to add header image at the place of the title Blog | Everyday California..

Answer (score 0):

The Blog title is being called from your header.php.  You would want to add the image before your blog title tag.

Something like

```
<img src="wp-content/uploads/header.jpg" /><h1 id="blog-title">
```

You can wrap it in a div and style or position it with css as well.

**Example**

```
<div id="header-img">
  <img src="wp-content/uploads/header.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-img {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Obviously this is a basic example of how to approach this.  If your blog title was not being called from header.php you would need to find where it coming from and make your changes from there.
A good Lesson from this should be to locate and learn where wordpress is calling whatever you would like to edit.  Things that appear on every page at the top are usually located in the header.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, just below the editor, this sentence is written - "You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See the Codex for more information."...

How do I change the permissions..?? Because of this I cannot do any modifications ?

Comment: Any time you have issues with permissions, this is done on the server side.  So you need to log in to your hosting and make sure your theme folder permissions are set to writeable. You can often do this through the file manager.  Change wp-content/themes/your_theme_name to 777.  Sometimes there are options to change all files inside to this permission but sometimes you have to change each folder and its contents individually.